# How to prove $((p\to(q\to r))) \to ((p\to q)\to(p\to r))$ is tautology without truth table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to prove this statement is tautology $(p\to(q\to r)) \to ((p\to q)\to(p\to r))$ without using truth table.

Comment: Use definition of $\Rightarrow$ and simplify using known rules.

Comment: I have tried but I can't arrive at the solution. Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Replace $a\rightarrow b$ with $\neg a \lor b$ and see what happens.

Comment: Alternatively, work through the expression. Assume it is false for some configuration. So that means $p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)$ is true and $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow (p\rightarrow r)$ is false, so $p\rightarrow r$ is false etc.. see where that takes you.

Comment: What tools do you have? Systematic tableau? Proof inference rules?

Comment: Logical equivalences

Answer (score 0):

Let us show that it is impossible for the statement to **not** be a tautology.

If the statement wasn't a tautology, there would exist some configuration of values for $p,q$ and $r$ such that the statement is false. By definition of implication, the only possibility for this to happen is that $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is true and that $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ is false.

Now, rewriting the first part (the one which must be true) we get

$$ \neg p \vee (\neg q \vee r) = \neg p \vee \neg q \vee r. $$

Since this statement must be true, we get that either $p$ is false, $q$ is false or $r$ is true (at least one of this conditions must be satisfied). We analyze these conditions:

- Suppose that $p$ is false: then $p \rightarrow q$ is true and furthermore $p \rightarrow r$ is also true, which means that the second statement is true, giving a contradiction. Hence $p$ can't be false **(p is true)**.
- Now suppose that $q$ is false. Since $p$ is true we have that $p \rightarrow q$ is false, which again means that the second statement is true, giving a contradiction. Hence $q$ can't be false **(q is true)**.
- The only possibility left is to let $r$ be true. Since we already know that $p$ and $q$ are both true, we have that $p \rightarrow q$ is also true and $p \rightarrow r$  is also true. Hence the second statement is true, which again is a contradiction.

Therefore, we've shown that if $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is true, it is impossible for $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ to be false, which is the only possible way that the statement in question isn't a tautology. Hence, the statement in question **is** a tautology.

Comment: Thank for all your answers. I finally arrived at the answer.

Comment: @T.K.Santhosh Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if you feel like it clarified your doubts. If any further doubt remains, make yourself "noisy"!